# How to Use the Program Printed Value for Another Operation in Python?

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, infinite-loop, arithmetic-expressions

Let say I have this simple operation:

```
x = 1
print x+1
```

How can you directly use the printed value from "print x+1" to do the same operation with it over and over.

I expect the output to be:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
.
.
.
```

Comment: don't print , assign result to variable - `value = x+1`

Comment: What about if I want to do it in a looping fashion? I mean I want python to recognize the printed value and use it by itself without assigning it to variable each time@furas

Comment: I don'ty know what you mean - edit question and add example - maybe you need list to keep all values

Answer (score 2):

```
x = 1
y = x+1
print y
# then do other/extra operations with "y"
```

Answer (score 2):

OK... I'll bite...

```
import sys
import io

class Hijacker(io.TextIOWrapper):
    def __init__(self):
        self.last_value = None
        self._odd = True

    def write(self, s):
        if self._odd:
            self.last_value = s
        sys.__stdout__.write(str(s))
        self._odd = not self._odd


    flush = sys.__stdout__ .flush
    read = sys.__stdout__ .read
    readline = sys.__stdout__.readline
    encoding = sys.__stdout__.encoding
    errors = sys.__stdout__ .errors

h = Hijacker()
sys.stdout = h

print(1)
print(1 + int(h.last_value))
print(1 + int(h.last_value))
```

Outputs:

```
1
2
3
```

That will only work when run from an actual shell, the interactive interpreter won't have any of it. I've also only tried it on Windows so WHO KNOWS if it'll work elsewhere. Don't ask me how it works, it's too horrible to comprehend. Also NEVER DO THIS. Like everyone else has already said, your approach is wrong. Loops and variables please!

Answer (score 0):

I agree with furas comment. Catching the print result makes little sense
in most cases.

If you have a reason to want the printout in a string, you can do this
by using `str()` instead of print.

```
x = 1
y = str(x+1)

y = y + "do something"
print y
```